# Virtual Directory in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, virtual-directory

In our web application we have a directory which resides outside of the project. On IIS that's no problem to do, but can I do that also in my project in Visual Studio?

**Edit:** My project is running on File System, and not on Local IIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click `File|Open|Website` and then click on the `Local IIS` button on the left-hand side of the dialog, then navigate to your project file and open from there you should find the virtual directories are included in Solution Explorer.

Comment: But I'm using File System, so my project isn't on my Local IIS. I'll update my question. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I'm more or less sure you can't do it in that case - the file system has no concept of vdirs, they're an IIS-only thing. Unless someone else knows better...